How can I call a function that's inside a controller?
I've built a product edit page for my web application, complete with standard input fields and buttons. Additionally, I've implemented a drag-and-drop feature for images. However, I'm encountering an issue with image storage.
Currently, when a user drags and drops an image, it's automatically saved to the local storage, even though I'd prefer not to store it until the user confirms the changes. Instead, I store the image name in the database.
To address this, I've implemented a delete function that checks for the existence of the image in the local storage and deletes it if necessary. This function is triggered when a user uploads a new image, ensuring that only the latest image is stored.
However, I've run into a problem. If a user decides to cancel the product edit, the old image is deleted, leaving no image associated with the product in the database.
To rectify this, I understand that I need to link the delete function to the save button. Thus, when the save button is clicked, the old image should be deleted, and the new image should be saved to the database.
To achieve this, I created a new function to call the delete image function when the button is pressed. However, I'm encountering an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
'emit').

I've tried various solutions, including using @livewireScript, but to no avail.
Below is the relevant code snippet from my view:
<div class="flex-1 relative">
    <livewire:add-products :product="$product"/>
    <div class="absolute bottom-5 right-5 flex space-x-2">
        <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" onclick="window.livewire.emit('deleteDroppedImage')"
                class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
            Submit
        </button>
        <button onclick="history.back()" type="button"
                class="focus:outline-none bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-700 focus:z-10 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-100 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center" >
            Cancel
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

And here's the function I've created to delete the dropped image:
<div>
    <img class="object-contain size-80 mx-auto rounded-lg mt-6 border-2 border-slate-400"
         src="{{$url}}"
         alt="Product Image">

    <input value="{{$url}}" name="productImg" hidden>
    <div
        class="flex mt-5 justify-center items-center"
        x-data="drop_file_component()">
        <div
            class="py-6 w-96 rounded border-dashed border-2 flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
            x-bind:class="dropingFile ? 'bg-gray-400 border-gray-500' : 'border-gray-500 bg-gray-200'"
            x-on:drop="dropingFile = false"
            x-on:drop.prevent="
                handleFileDrop($event)
            "
            x-on:dragover.prevent="dropingFile = true"
            x-on:dragleave.prevent="dropingFile = false">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-16 w-16" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 13h6m-3-3v6m-9 1V7a2 2 0 012-2h6l2 2h6a2 2 0 012 2v8a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2z" />
            </svg>
            <div class="text-center" wire:loading.remove wire.target="files">Drop Your Files Here</div>
            <div class="mt-1" wire:loading.flex wire.target="files">
                <svg class="animate-spin -ml-1 mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-700" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <circle class="opacity-25" cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="4"></circle>
                    <path class="opacity-75" fill="currentColor" d="M4 12a8 8 0 018-8V0C5.373 0 0 5.373 0 12h4zm2 5.291A7.962 7.962 0 014 12H0c0 3.042 1.135 5.824 3 7.938l3-2.647z"></path>
                </svg>
                <div>Processing Files</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        function drop_file_component() {
            return {
                dropingFile: false,
                handleFileDrop(e) {
                    if (event.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
                        const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
                    @this.uploadMultiple('files', files,
                        (uploadedFilename) => {}, () => {}, (event) => {}
                    )
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
</div>


I've also ensured that the delete function is properly linked to the Livewire component in my controller:
    public function deleteDroppedImage()
    {
        \Log::info('URL: ' . $this->url); // Log the URL
        \Log::info('Product picture: ' . $this->product->picture); // Log the product picture

        if ($this->url != 'https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/default-image-icon-vector-missing-picture-page-website-design-mobile-app-no-photo-available_87543-11093.jpg') {
            $imagePath = '/photos/' . $this->product->picture;
            \Log::info('Image path: ' . $imagePath); // Log the image path

            if (Storage::disk('public')->exists($imagePath)) {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($imagePath);
            } else {
                \Log::info('Image not found at path: ' . $imagePath); // Log if the image is not found
            }
        }
    }

I'd appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
edit: i also have this in my controller (where the delete function is): protected $listeners = ['deleteDroppedImage' => 'deleteDroppedImage'];

The optimal approach to handle this situation is to utilize Livewire's temporary upload directory when editing the product until the user submits the changes. DO NOT update the image name in the database until that point.
All temporary files will be automatically deleted. Livewire cleans up files older than 24 hours.
However, once the user submits their changes, you may need to update (delete and replace) the image with the new one.
